# supersized.js integration with wordpress post atachment

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Any suggestions of how to integrate wordpress post image attachments into the array required by supersized.js for easy formatting?

http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/
http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.1/fade.html

It needs images in an array like -

slides : [   //Slideshow Images
{image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.1/slides/quietchaos-kitty.jpg', title : 'Quiet Chaos by Kitty Gallannaugh', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2010/12/kitty-gallannaugh/'},
{image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.1/slides/wanderers-kitty.jpg', title : 'Wanderers by Kitty Gallannaugh', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2010/12/kitty-gallannaugh/'},
{image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.1/slides/apple-kitty.jpg', title : 'Applewood by Kitty Gallannaugh', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2010/12/kitty-gallannaugh/'}
]

I've found this - 
https://www.wpoutfitters.com/2011/01/wordpress-image-attachment-gallery-revisited/
but not sure how to make it fit for an array.

this websites seems to be able to use supersized.js with images in the html body
http://www.cstone.com.au

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var imgpad = $("img.bgscaler").prop('src');
    jQuery(function($){
        $.supersized({
            slides : [ {image : imgpad, title : 'Achtergrond'} ]
        });
    }); 
});
```

After you have loaded the image into your site, you can extract the src url and put it into
a variable. Now you can input this into supersized.
Make sure that you give the image some css to put it on display:none.

That's it.